# Writing a questionaire in R

Tags: r

My target is to create a function named "questionaire()" to ask for the following three questions:

```
Question 1: Where do you live?
Question 2: For how many years have you been there?
Question 3: What is your gender?
```

I want my function to be interactive, so I want to have display the questions one by one to ask the users to input their responds. I expect a positive integer numeric value for answers in question 2 and "M" or "F" for question 3, so I guess I can set some input verifications here, so that if the inputs from the user are not defined, we would display the same question again. All answers will then be stored in a data frame with three variables

```
Homeland Years Gender
```

as an output of this function.

And when a set of three questions is completed, the program will display a message:

```
New entry? <Y/N>:
```

such that if the input is "Y", a new respondent is expected to answer those three questions with their answers stored as a new observation of the output data frame, and if the input is "N", the function is terminated with the following tasks:

The table of information would be collected would be displayed, for example:

```
 Homeland Years Gender
1 Ben      20   M
2 Amy      22   F
3 Luca     18   M
```

The years are summarized with a statement, for instance:

```
The average number of year living in the homeland is 20 from 3 responents.
```

Lastly, a pie chart is displayed to show the gender distribution.

Suppose I am not going to use any library. I guess I am going to use loop, and I am not sure how to do the interaction part. Can anyone tell me how can I generate the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Without any error checking, a sample code will be like below.

```
test <- function(){
  again='Y'
  result=NULL
  while (again=='Y')
  {
    Homeland <- readline("Question 1: Where do you live?")  
    Years <- readline("Question 2: For how many years have you been there?")
    Gender <- readline("Question 3: What is your gender?")
    again <- readline("New entry? <Y/N>:")
    result=rbind(result, data.frame(Homeland=Homeland,Years=Years,Gender=Gender))
  }
  print(result)
  cnt=nrow(result)
  avg=mean(as.numeric(result$Years))
  print(paste('The average number of year living in the homeland is ',avg,' from ',cnt,' responents.'))
  pie(summary(factor(result$Gender)))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But how can I initiate the questionaire? I mean how can I make it display the questions?

Comment: Opps nth, simply type "test()" will do.